# Share index and .htaccess files between multiple domains

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cpanel, whm

I have some domains where i replicate the index and .htaccess files, the structure is:

```
/home/user1/public_html
    .htaccess
    index.php

/home/user2/public_html
    .htaccess
    index.php

        .
        .
        .

/home/userN/public_html
    .htaccess
    index.php
```

When i have to update these files, it is a great headache, i need to do it one by one. I tried to create soft symlinks, but i got a 500 internal error.

Is there a way to unify these files using some Apache or Linux feature? I am using CentOS, Apache and WHM/cPanel.

**EDIT 1**

Resumed content of each file

**index.php**

```
<?php

$ini = parse_ini_file('../system/ini/app.ini');

require_once($ini['env_path'] . '/' . $ini['env_name'] . '/IniHandler.php');

$IniHandler = new IniHandler();

require_once($IniHandler->getFullEnvPath() . '/frontcontroller-site.php');
```

**.htaccess**

```
Options -Indexes

ErrorDocument 404 /errormessages/404.php

DirectoryIndex index.php?module=site&controller=Main&action=index

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([A-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)/?(.+)*$ /index.php?module=$1&controller=$2&action=$3&aux_get_vars=$4 [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Do you have SSH access to the server? Can you access/change the apache httpd config?

Comment: @Scolytus, Yes, it is a VPS that i have access

Comment: If you have ssh access then you cand just text manipulation tools like sed/awk etc. If you can provide more infos about what you actually try to add/update in those .htaccess files I can provide you with a command that will do the job for you.

Comment: @BogdanStoica, I updated the question, now it has a resume of the files content. Note that i can't update all accounts, i have to update only specific users that use a specific app, these files connect to main app to show their sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that you have to update just specific accounts and I suppose that you already know which accounts are those, then you can do it by using a simple bash script. You have to create an array first, array that contains the files that are supposed to be modified.

**Bash script example:**

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a files=('/home/cpaneluser/public_html/.htaccess' '/home/cpaneluser1/public_html/.htaccess' '/home/cpaneluser2/public_html/.htaccess' '..' '..');
for i in "${files[@]}"
do
    echo "abc" >> $i # add abc text at the end of the file
    sed -i '9i9 This is Line 9' $i # add This is Line 9 on line 9 in the text file
done
```

The script above will add text **abc** to the following files:

```
- /home/cpaneluser/public_html/.htaccess
- /home/cpaneluser1/public_html/.htaccess
- /home/cpaneluser2/public_html/.htaccess
```

Of course this is just a generic example but I believe it's a good starting point. Probably it requires a little time to build the initial file list but you have to define those files anyway. You can then modify/adapt this script according to your needs.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks! As you said, it is a great starting point! Is it possible to add an entry in a specific line?

Comment: I have updated my answer accordingly (adding a specific text at a specific line for all the files within the array)

Comment: Could you please edit the answer to replace the files instead of edit? I think it will be more simple.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean really!

Comment: I think the purpose of this website is to help people to solve different issues. For that to happen you are supposed to try at least!

Comment: Sorry, i wasn't clear. Firstly, i would like to say that i am not familiarized with bash commands. I asked in the previous comment if you can edit the answer to replace entirely the two files when i run the bash. Thanks once more and sorry for any misunderstanding.